# Ruby on Rails: Define a variable for a certain timestamp, which can be edited by the app user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

my goal is to define a variable (@deadline) for a certain timestamp, which can be edited by the app user. I had the approach to solve that problem by creating a show view, which offers a form to the user.

```
<%= link_to "Anmeldefrist setzen", show_deadline_path(@deadline), :method => 'get' %>
```

that show view is accessible and works how I want it, the struggle starts, when I push the button to submit the timestamp.

```
<% if logged_in? and current_user.admin? %>
  <% provide(:title, "Anmeldefrist setzen") %>
  <div class="small_jumbotron jumbotron">
    <h1> Anmeldefrist setzen </h1>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="Links">
        <%= form_tag(:controller => "preferences", :action  => "update_deadline", :method => :put) do %>
          <%= label @deadline, "Anmeldefrist" %>
          <br>
          <%= datetime_select @deadline, value: @deadline %>
          <br>
          <%= submit_tag "Speichern", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          <br>
        <% end %>
        <h2> <%= link_to image_tag('back2.png'), matching_path %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The routes file doesn't accept the method "put" from the form. I also tried to do it with "patch" before. I always get a routing error.

```
No route matches [POST] "/update_deadline"
```

I will add log file, routes.rb and controller now, thanks to everyone, who tries to help! You can also criticize my approach and propose another one, but I would appreaciate detailed instructions.

Thanks! Kind regards 
Moritz

Log:
        Started GET "/show_deadline" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-07 16:45:48 +0100
        Processing by PreferencesController#show_deadline as HTML
          Rendering preferences/show_deadline.html.erb within layouts/application
          [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
          Rendered preferences/show_deadline.html.erb within layouts/application (20.8ms)
          Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (131.7ms)
          Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.8ms)
          Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.6ms)
          Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.8ms)
        Completed 200 OK in 183ms (Views: 180.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

```
    Started POST "/update_deadline?method=put" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-07 16:45:54 +0100

    ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/update_deadline"):

    actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
    web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
    web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
    web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
    web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
    actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
    railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
    railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
    activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
    activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
    activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
    railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
    actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
    actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
    rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
    activesupport (5.1.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
    actionpack (5.1.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
    rack (2.0.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
    railties (5.1.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
    puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
    puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
    puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
    puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
    puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :preferences
  resources :institutes
  resources :users
  resources :admin, to: 'users#admin'

  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get '/matching', to: 'static_pages#matching'
  get '/cockpit', to: 'static_pages#cockpit'

  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup',  to: 'users#create'

  get '/performance_show', to: 'users#performance_show'
  get '/performance_update', to: 'users#performance_update'

  post 'preferences/create_all', :to => 'preferences#create_all'

  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  get '/show_deadline', :to => 'preferences#show_deadline'
  patch '/update_deadline', :to => 'preferences#update_deadline'

  post 'preferences/delete_matching', :to => 'preferences#delete_matching'
  post 'preferences/read_and_show_ofv', :to => 'preferences#read_and_show_ofv'
  post 'preferences/read_matching', :to => 'preferences#read_matching'
  post 'preferences/optimize_matching', :to => 'preferences#optimize_matching'

  post 'preferences/optimize', to: 'preferences#optimize'

end
```

Controller:

```
  def show_deadline
    if @deadline.nil?
      @deadline = 0
    end
  end

  def update_deadline
    if @deadline.update_attributes
      flash[:success] = "Die Deadline wurde aktualisiert."
      redirect_to matching_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Die Präferenz konnte nicht aktualisiert werden."
      redirect_to preferences_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: Why all the trouble with put/patch? This method is not dealing with a resource anyway, just make it a POST.

Comment: Is the variable still editable, if I use "post" instead od "patch/put"?

Comment: I followed your advice, which returns another error message:                   undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass          seems like the show view function is not able to make deadline not nil and the submit of the form doesn't fill the variable @deadline as well

Comment: That sounds like a really convoluted way of just adding a datetime field to your model which you can edit just like any other.

Comment: What would be an easy way?

Comment: Just add a datetime field to whatever model has a deadline and edit via the normal edit / update action.

Comment: Actually I don't have a certain model, which has a deadline attribute. The deadline is meant for the whole application to make it unaccessible for users at a certain date.

Comment: But I could add it to the preference model... I will try to do that. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah otherwise what are you actually going to do with the instance variable? You have to save it somewhere or it just disappears after rails finishes with the request.

Comment: I just think that the application would have a few hundred preferences and all of them will have the same attribute deadline with an identical value.Isn't that a little bit unefficient? Isn't there a way to define a global variable $deadline, which doesn't disappear after the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist the instance variable somewhere or it will just disappear into thin air after rails is done with the request - that somewhere might as well be a model.

Create a migration and add the datetime field to your model:

```
rails g migration add_deadline_to_preferences deadline:datetime
```

Add a validation that ensures that the time is in the future:

```
class Preference < ApplicationRecord
  validate :deadline_is_not_elapsed

  private 
  def deadline_is_not_elapsed
    errors.add(:deadline, 'Deadline has elapsed') if deadline > Time.now
  end
end
```

Add the attribute to the form:

```
<%= form_with(model: @preference || Preference.new) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :deadline %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :deadline, start_year: Time.now.year, default: 3.days.from_now  %>
  </div>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

And whitelist it:

```
def preference_attributes
  params.require(:preference).permit(:foo, :bar, :deadline)
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that detailed instruction! Could you please answer one more small question?                                                                     I just think that the application would have a few hundred preferences and all of them will have the same attribute deadline with an identical value.Isn't that a little bit unefficient? Isn't there a way to define a global variable $deadline, which doesn't disappear after the request?

Comment: I just thought it would be more efficient to create a new model called deadline instead of adding it to preferences, where it doesn't really belong to.

Comment: That depends completely on the problem domain. You could also just create a singular `SystemConfiguration` resource and store it on that table.